# Get all children of parents which matches query in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am working on elastic search 6.5 and using joint datatype for parent-child relationship.
I am able to create the index with few parents and associated children.

Now I want to search all childrens of the parents which matches the phrase entered . eg. If user enter 'San' then query should search all parents matching this phrase . i.e sand,sandwich,sanitizer. And then using them as 'id' return all the childrens too.

I tried to use 'parent_id' but it doesn't work with match query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "parent_id": { 
      "type": "answer",
      "id": "1"
    }
  }
```

The above query I can search for childrens but parent id has to be mentioned completely,but I am looking for something where you can match pharase and search.

Could you please help me and direct towards right approach.

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [has_parent](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-parent-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "type": "parent_type", --> replace with parent join_field value
      "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
          "FIELD": "PHRASE"
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {} --> will return child documents
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It helped me.I was just looking at documentation . 'has_child' executes query on child documents and return the parent documents. So I changed it to 'has_parent' and it worked for me .   {
      "query": {
        "has_parent": {
          "parent_type": "search",
          "score":true,
          "query" : {
                "match_phrase_prefix" : {
                    "search" : {
                        "query" : "san"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }